# How to prove that $2< e <4$ by the definition of logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

I have already read one similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156442/prove-that-2-e-4-using-upper-and-lower-riemann-sums-and-the-definition-of) on this topic but I can't use Riemann sums to prove that as instead is done here. The only thing I can use is the definition of $ln(x) = \int^x_1\frac1tdt$ and the known properties of logarithm (i.e. $ln(xy) = ln(x)+ln(y), ln(a^n) = nln(a)$) and properties of integrals.

My book is terrible about it: it just exposes this:

$2 < e < 4$, in fact $\frac12 < ln(2)$ (even this I don't get why) $< 1 = \int^2_11dt$ (for monotony of integrals) $< 2ln(2) = ln(4)$ without explaining why $\frac12 < ln(2)$ and $1 < 2ln(2)$. If you could please give me some info about this I would really love you. (mostly about $ 1 < 2ln(2) $ ).

Thanks.

Comment: If you can use the definition of log as an integral, then the argument with rectangles in the link you've provided is the simplest possible. Just don't call it Riemann sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition of $\log x = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$, fundamental theorem of calculus tell us

$$\frac{d}{dx}\log(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} = \frac{1}{x}$$

If one define $e$ to be the number such that $\log(e) = 1$, one must have $e > 1$
because the integrand $\frac{1}{t}$ is positive. Furthermore, since the derivative is positive, we have  $\log(x) < 1$ when $x < e$ and $\log(x) > 1$ when $x > e$.

Consider the function $\frac{\log(x)}{x}$ for $x \ge 1$, we have:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right) = \frac{1-\log(x)}{x^2}
\begin{cases}
> 0, & x < e\\
= 0, & x = e\\
< 0, & x > e
\end{cases}
$$
So the function $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is strictly increasing on $[1,e]$ and strictly decreasing on $[e,\infty)$.

Since $2 \ne 4$ but $$\frac{\log(4)}{4} = \frac{\log(2 \times 2)}{4} = \frac{2\log(2)}{4} = \frac{\log(2)}{2}$$
$2$ and $4$ need to fall into different intervals $[1,e]$ and $[e, \infty)$. Furthermore, none of them can equal to $e$. Together with $2 < 4$, we obtain
$$2 \in [1,e),\;4 \in (e, \infty)\quad\iff\quad 2 < e < 4 $$

Comment: I'm not getting the part: $log(x)/x$ is strictly incresing implies $x^(1/x)$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: @Bafforasta I have get rid of that. Showing that need to define $e^x$ and justify its properties.

Comment: Thanks, your demonstration is enough rigid to be exposed in an exam (as it has to). Thanks to everybody

Answer (score 5):

Let's prove that $\ln 2 < 1 < \ln 4$.

Consider the graph of $\dfrac1x$.

The rectangle $[1,2] \times [0,1]$ contains the area of the graph for $x \in [1,2]$. Therefore, $\ln 2 < 1$.

The rectangles $[1,2] \times [0,\dfrac12]$ and $[2,4] \times [0,\dfrac14]$ are contained in area of the graph for $x \in [2,4]$. Therefore, $\ln 4 > 1$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$\frac 1t < 1$ for $t >1$ so $\ln 2=\int\limits_{1}^2 \frac 1 dt <1*[2-1]=1$

$\frac 1t >\frac 12$ for $1 <t <2$ and $\frac 1t > \frac 14$ for $2\le t <4$, so $\ln 4=\int\limits_{1}^4 \frac 1 dt >\frac 14*[2-1]+\frac 14 [4-2]=1$.

Finally note that as $\frac 1t >0$ for all positive $t $, $\ln $ is monotonically increasing.

So $\ln 2 < 1=\ln e < \ln 4$ we know $2 < e < 4$.