# Prove that $s_n \leq 1+\ln n$, where $s_n$ is the $n$th partial sum of the harmonic series

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers

This is a very Interesting question, there are many ways to do it.

Lets see what is the best way to do it.

I have an idea which involves a definite integral, I am working on it, will post it soon.

Comment: Did you try searching this site?

Comment: I did search around

Comment: I have tried searching for [harmonic number inequality site:math.stackexchange.com](http://images.google.com/images?q=harmonic+number+inequality+site:math.stackexchange.com) in Google Images. On of the results is [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156326/showing-inequality-for-harmonic-series), which seems like a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each integer $m \ge 2$, we have $\dfrac{1}{m} = \displaystyle\int_{m-1}^{m}\dfrac{1}{m}\,dx \le \int_{m-1}^{m}\dfrac{1}{x}\,dx$.

Sum this up from $m = 2$ to $m = n$ to get $\displaystyle\sum_{m = 2}^{n}\dfrac{1}{m} \le \sum_{m = 2}^{n}\int_{m-1}^{m}\dfrac{1}{x}\,dx = \int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{x}\,dx = \ln n$.

Then, add $1$ to both sides to get $s_n = \displaystyle\sum_{m = 1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{m} \le 1+\ln n$.

EDIT: Here is a good picture to go with this proof.

[image]
Source:http://mathfactor.uark.edu/images/harmonic2.jpg

Answer (score 2):

As you are going to do it by integration, I will do it by differentiation.  Using the Mean Value Theorem (that's the differentiation bit) one can prove that
$$\ln x>1-\frac{1}{x}\quad\hbox{for}\quad x>1\ .$$
In particular,
$$\ln(n+1)-\ln n=\ln\Bigl(\frac{n+1}{n}\Bigr)>\frac{1}{n+1}\quad\hbox{for}\quad n\ge1\ .$$
This can now be used to provide an easy inductive proof of your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

What I a thinking is $$s_n = \int_0^1 \left(1+x+x^2+....x^{n-1}\right) \hspace{1mm}dx$$

Comment: To continue, note that we have two inequalities for your integrand $f(x)$: if $0\le x\le1$ then$$f(x)\le1+1+\cdots+1=n$$and$$f(x)\le1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x}\ .$$Hence$$S_n\le\int_0^{1-(1/n)}\frac{dx}{1-x}+\int_{1-(1/n)}^1 n\,dx\ .$$