# $ \frac{1}{2} + \dots + \frac{1}{n} \le \log n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, logarithms, harmonic-numbers

could anyone give me any hint how to prove this ?

$$ \frac{1}{2} + \dots + \frac{1}{n} \le \log n $$

just came acroos this expression in my book.

Comment: Do you know that $$\log n = \int_1^n \frac{dx}{x}\,?$$

Comment: yes..:/ how is that going to help me? :/

Comment: See below, the answer by SRX is pretty detailed.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156326/showing-inequality-for-harmonic-series).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix a positive integer $k$. Using the fact that $g(x) = x^{-1}$ is decreasing on $[k,k+1]$, we have
$$(k+1)^{-1} \leq x^{-1} \leq k^{-1} \text{ for } x \in [k,k+1]$$
Integrating over $[k,k+1]$ yields
$$\int_k^{k+1} (k+1)^{-1} dx\leq\int_k^{k+1}  x^{-1} dx\leq\int_k^{k+1}  k^{-1} dx$$
$$(k+1)^{-1} \leq\log(k+1) - \log(k)\leq k^{-1} $$
Summing up over $k = 1,2, \ldots, n-1$ we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k+1)^{-1} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} [\log(k+1) - \log(k)] \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^{-1} $$
$$2^{-1} + 3^{-1} + \ldots + n^{-1}\leq \log(n) \leq 1 + 2^{-1} + \ldots + (n-1)^{-1} $$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\log n=\int_1^n \frac{1}{x} \, dx$$

Note that if we take right handed sums with subinterval 1, we see that the sum of them is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$. And because the right handed sums are lower than the graph of $f(x)=\frac1x$ , we see that their area is smaller than the actual integral, that is, $\log x$.

Comment: Indeed, these are the left sums, which are an upper bound; you want the right sums, which are a lower bound.

Answer (score 2):

Use the inequality $$\frac{1}{n+1} \leqslant \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)$$ to prove yours by induction.