# Show that $45<x_{1000}<45.1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> If $x_0 = 5$ and $x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac {1}{x_n},$ show that
>
> $45<x_{1000}<45.1$
>
> This problem is taken from the list submitted for the $1975$ Canadian Mathematics Olympiad (but not used on the actual exam).
>
> **SOURCE :** [CRUX](http://imomath.com/pcpdf/f1/f41.pdf)(Page Number 3 ; Question Number 162)

I tried writing out the first few terms :

$x_1 = 5+ \frac{1}{5} $

$x_2 = \big(5+\frac{1}{5}\big) + \big(5+\frac{1}{5}\big)^{-1} = \frac{x_0^2 + 1}{x_0} +  \frac{x_0}{x_0^2 + 1} = \frac{(x_0^2 + 1)^2+x_0^2}{x_0(x_0^2+1)}$

$x_3 = \frac{(x_0^2 + 1)^2+x_0^2}{x_0(x_0^2+1)} + \frac{x_0(x_0^2+1)}{(x_0^2 + 1)^2+x_0^2} = Messy$

I tried a lot but could not find any general formula for the $n$th term. Does there even exist any?

Also it is clear that $\big(x_n + \frac{1}{x_n}\big)$ is an increasing function. So I think sequence diverges, but how can the $1000th$ term be calculated or aprroximated?

Any help would be gratefully acknowledged :).

Comment: Do you mean $x_{n}+\frac{1}{x_{n}}$ or $x_{n}+\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @S.C.B. OH sorry...just a typo .. edit on its way...

Comment: This sounds like something you can probably do using an approximation by the continuous version of this problem, i.e. $f'(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$. A first approximation would be $\sqrt{2\cdot 1000 + 5} \sim 44.78$, so this may still need a little bit of tweaking.

Comment: @Nirbhay, I love your $=Messy$ evaluation. Nice touch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**CLAIM**

For all $n \ge 1$, then let us prove $$\sqrt{2n+25+\frac{1+\ln (n-1)}{2}} > x_{n} > \sqrt{2n+25}$$
**PROOF**

This holds for $n=1$. This can be checked numerically.

Assume this holds for $n=m$. Then, we can prove the left hand inequality through induction as $$x_{m+1}^2=x_{m}^2+2+\frac{1}{x_{m}^2}>2n+27 \implies x_{m+1} > \sqrt{2n+27}$$
Now from $x_{m+1}^2-x_{m}^2=2+\frac{1}{x_{m}^2}$, we now have $$x_{m+1}^2-x_{0}^2=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \frac{1}{x_{n}^2}<\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{2n+25}<\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2n}\le \frac{1+\ln m}{2} \tag{1}$$
Thus, our claim is proved. 
The desired result follows from our Claim.

$(1)$: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156326/showing-inequality-for-harmonic-series)

**NOTE**: My original answer was wrong, which is the reason for this rather large edit.

Comment: Amazing answer. What was the intuition behind the "claim" ??

Comment: @Nirbhay I have often been thinking about radicals, so $x_{n}+\frac{1}{x_n}$ felt like it could be expressed using radicals.

Comment: I would also like to know how one comes up with this kind of bound for a recursive sequence.

Comment: @user1892304 Intuition :) I can't explain it completely myself.

Comment: @S.C.B. You did the question as if you knew its official solution. That's crazy !!!

Comment: @Nirbhay Not quite as crazy as you might think. I always think of math problems when I'm idle, and I always wanted to find the closed form the recurrence relation you posted. All I could succeed in is bounding it, which is how I knew the answer. Could you acept my answer?

Comment: Friend, have you participated in the IMO or something? You deserve the gold!

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I could have participaed. I watched the FKMO 2016, which picks Korean representatives for FKMO. Unfortunately, that year's FKMO was way~ too easy (so you had to get 100% or 83% to actually participate in the IMO) and I had been way to busy studying chemistry to properly prepare (so I slept through 2 thirds of it, getting only about a 70%). Hey, I saw you today. I answered your problem regarding $3x^2+x=4y^2+y$ didn't I?

Comment: @yes you answered it. Seems like you have the same problems like me, I have to learn 9 other subjects in addition to math. Which Olympiad books do you practice?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I'm finished with Olympiads for now. Math alone was hard enough. You have to pass $3$ tests, passing through the span of a year! I also studied chemistry and physics, and got a gold medal (I could have gotten $1$st place but for $1$ measely point) and a grand award respectively. I also studied for biology, but didn't get to actually watch the exam. I studied with Korean books, but I also studied all of "Modern Chemistry" by Oxtoby and "Modern Physics" by Halliday.

Comment: So you are still at school? How old are you, about to enter college? And it's awesome your cleared ChO and PhO. It's my aim too! Anyway I'm in 10 th grade

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I am the same age as you. Well, in my language I am 17 but in yours I am 15 and a half.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52684/discussion-between-s-c-b-and-n-s-john).

Answer (score 10):

$x_n^2-x_{n-1}^2=2+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}^2}$ for $n\geq1$.

Thus, $$x_{1000}^2=2\cdot1000+25+\frac{1}{x_0^2}+\frac{1}{x_1^2}+...+\frac{1}{x_{999}^2}>2025$$
and $$x_{1000}^2=2\cdot1000+25+\frac{1}{x_0^2}+\frac{1}{x_1^2}+...+\frac{1}{x_{999}^2}<2025+\frac{100}{x_0^2}+\frac{900}{x_{100}^2}<$$
$$<2025+4+\frac{900}{225}=2033<45.1^2$$

Because $x_{100}^2>225$.