# $\sum_{m=1}^{N}\lfloor{\frac{N}{m}\rfloor} \sim N \log N$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Let $d(n)$, the number of divisors of $n$. I am trying to show that
$\sum_{n \leq N}d(n) = \#\{(m,k) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}: mk \leq N\} =   \sum_{m=1}^{N}\lfloor{\frac{N}{m}\rfloor} \sim N \log N$

I am stuck at showing the asymptotic and how to deal with the floor function. We say $f(n) \sim g(n)$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1$.

Attempt:

$\lfloor{\frac{N}{m}\rfloor} = \frac{N}{m} + O(1)$. Hence we have $\frac{\frac{N}{m} + O(1)}{N \log N}$.

I am not sure if I can ignore the "Big oh" but think I can as its just a constant. I then tried applying L'hopital by differentiating w.r.t. $N$.

$\frac{1}{m}(N \log N)^{-1} + \frac{N}{m}\Big( \frac{-N \log N + 1}{N^{2}\log^{2}N}\Big)$. But I don't then seem to be able to get this to evaluate out to $1$,I keep ending up with a log factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see how you come up with the term $\frac{\frac{N}{m} + O(1)}{N \log N}$. If $\lfloor{\frac{N}{m}\rfloor} = \frac{N}{m} + O(1)$ then $\sum_{m=1}^{N}\lfloor{\frac{N}{m}\rfloor} = N \sum_{m=1}^{N} \frac 1m + O(N) = N \log N + O(N)$.

More precisely: You can estimate $f(N) = \sum_{m=1}^{N}\left\lfloor \frac{N}{m}\right\rfloor$ from above with
$$
f(N)  \le \sum_{m=1}^{N} \frac Nm = N \sum_{m=1}^{N} \frac 1m \le N( 1 + \log N)
$$
and from below with
$$
f(N)  \ge \sum_{m=1}^{N} \left(\frac Nm -1 \right) = N \sum_{m=1}^{N} \frac 1m - N \ge N \log N - N \, ,
$$
using [$\log N<\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}<1+\log N.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156326/showing-inequality-for-harmonic-series)

It follows that
$$
1 - \frac{1}{\log N} \le \frac{f(N)}{N \log N} \le 1 + \frac{1}{\log N}
$$
and therefore
$$ 
\lim_{N \to \infty } \frac{f(N)}{N \log N} = 1 \, .
$$

---

As @Conrad said, one can use the symmetry of the set $\{(m,k) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}: mk \leq N\}$ to obtain a better asymptotic expression:
$$
 \sum_{n \leq N}d(n) = 2 \sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor }
\left\lfloor \frac{N}{m}\right\rfloor
- (\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor)^2
= 2 N \sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor } \frac 1m - N + O(\sqrt N) \, .
$$
Using the asymptotic expansion $H_N = \log N + \gamma + O(1/N)$ for the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) this gives
$$
\sum_{n \leq N}d(n) = N \log N + (2\gamma -1) N + O(\sqrt N) \, .
$$

Comment: You can actually get a better asymptotic by using the hyperbola trick where you sum the divisors only to square root and then one gets $N\log N +(2\gamma-1)N + O(\sqrt N)$

Comment: @Martin R thanks! To answer your initial question, I got that term but just immediately applying the definition of $f(x) \sim g(x)$ (but omitting the summation).

Comment: @Conrad: Yes, thanks, I have made a short addendum.