# $\log{n} + \frac{1}{n} < H_n < \log{n} + 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, harmonic-numbers

I see on that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156326/showing-inequality-for-harmonic-series) post that the inequality $\log{n} < H_n < \log{n} + 1$ is proven. However, *Proofs from THE BOOK* takes it a step further, and states that $\log{n} + \frac{1}{n} < H_n < \log{n} + 1$. Its explanation is as follows:

Let

$$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}.$$

Consider the following image:

[image: this]

From it, we can derive that,

$$H_n - 1 = \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k} < \int_1^n \frac{1}{t}dt = \log{n}$$

by comparing the area below the graph of $f(t) = \frac{1}{t} (1 \leq t \leq n)$ with the area of the dark shaded rectangles, and

$$H_n - \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k} > \int_1^n \frac{1}{t}dt = \log{n}$$

by comparing the area of the large (including the lightly shaded parts). Taken together, this yields,

$$\log{n} + \frac{1}{n} < H_n < \log{n} + 1.$$

I understand where the $\log{n} + 1$ comes from (it is explained in the aforementioned post on the same topic), but I don't understand the $\log{n} + \frac{1}{n}$, nor its explanation. Can anyone help?

Comment: if we have $g(x) > 0$ but $g'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; g(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  g(j) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  g(x) \; dx   $$

Comment: the $\log(n)+\frac{1}{n}$ comes from the second inequality after moving the $\frac{1}{n}$ to the other side. The inequality comes from the upper Riemann sum and since $$\int=\sup{\Sigma_U}$$, where $ \Sigma_U$ is a upper sum, the inequality follows trivially

Comment: $$ \int_1^{n+1} \; \frac{1}{x} \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=1}^n \;  \frac{1}{j} \; < \; \int_{0}^n \; \frac{1}{x} \; dx   $$   but also $$ \int_2^{n+1} \; \frac{1}{x} \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=2}^n \;  \frac{1}{j} \; < \; \int_{1}^n \; \frac{1}{x} \; dx   $$  and    $$1 + \int_2^{n+1} \; \frac{1}{x} \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=1}^n \;  \frac{1}{j} \; < \; 1+ \int_{1}^n \; \frac{1}{x} \; dx   $$   so $$ 1 - \log 2 + \log(n+1)  < H_n < 1 + \log n $$

Comment: Notice that the sum extends to $n-1$, so we are missing the term $1/n$

Comment: $$ 1 - \log 2 + \log(n+1)  < H_n < 1 + \log n $$  and $$ 1 - \log 2 + \log(1 + \frac{1}{n})  <  H_n  - \log n < 1  $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image depicts $n-1$ large rectangles, each with width $1$. The first rectangle is placed over the interval $[1,2]$, the second over the interval $[2,3]$, the final one over the interval $[n-1,n]$. Their corresponding heights are $\frac11$, $\frac12,\ldots,\frac1{n-1}$. Hence their total area is
$$\frac11+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k.$$ By inspection, the total area of these large rectangles exceeds the area under the curve $y=\frac1t$ from $t=1$ to $t=n$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k > \int_{t=1}^{t=n}\frac1t\,dt.$$
The assertion $H_n-\frac1n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k$ follows from the definition of $H_n$; the assertion $\int_1^n\frac1t\,dt=\log n$ is calculus. Put everything together to conclude $H_n -\frac1n > \log n$.