# Limit of $\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(i-\alpha)$

Tags: limits, infinite-product

Suppose that $\alpha > 0$. Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{1}\right)\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{n}\right)=0$$
Here’s what I’ve tried so far,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{1}\right)\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{n}\right) &\leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{n}\right)^n\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Since $\alpha$ is positive, then the LHS limit is positive as well. As such, can we simply conclude that LHS limit is $0$?

Comment: We have $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( 1- \frac{\alpha}{n} \right)^n = e^{-\alpha} \neq 0.$$

Comment: Positive precludes zero, so you mean nonnegative not positive. Why would $\alpha$ positive imply this though? For $\alpha=1.5$ for example the product on the LHS is always negative. Anyway, ignoring all factors with $n<\alpha$, we can take the logarithm of the truncated product and use $\log(1+x)=x+{\cal O}(x^2)$ for $|x|<1$ to see the product must diverge to $0$, so at least your conclusion is true.

Comment: To elaborate a bit on runway44's comment. First show that $L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \prod_{j=1}^n \left( 1-\frac{\alpha}{n}\right)$ exists (use monotonicity after a certain index and boundedness). If $L\neq 0$, then pick $s\in \{\pm 1\}$ such that $sL>0$ and observe that $$\ln(sL) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \ln \left( s \prod_{j=1}^n \left(1-\frac{\alpha}{n}\right) \right) = \ln\left( s\prod_{j=1}^N \left(1-\frac{\alpha}{n}\right) \right) + \sum_{j=N+1}^n \ln\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{j}\right).$$ Now use runway's comment to show that the series diverges which gives the desired contradiction.

Comment: Of course the factors in the formula in my previous comment should be $\left( 1-\frac{\alpha}{j}\right)$, not $\left( 1-\frac{\alpha}{n}\right)$.

Comment: $$
\frac{1}{{n!}}\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {(i - \alpha )}  = \frac{1}{{\Gamma (1 - \alpha )}}\frac{{\Gamma (n + 1 - \alpha )}}{{\Gamma (n + 1)}} \sim \frac{1}{{\Gamma (1 - \alpha )}}\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^\alpha  }}
$$

Comment: Handle the case $\alpha\in\Bbb N$ separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ln\prod_{n>\alpha}\left(1-\frac\alpha n\right)=\sum_{n>\alpha}\ln\left(1-\frac\alpha n\right)=-\infty,$ because $\ln(1+x)\sim_{x\to0}x$ and the harmonic series diverges.

Therefore, $\prod_{n>\alpha}\left(1-\frac\alpha n\right)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use [the inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504663/215011) $1+x\le e^x$ to see
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n\left( 1 -\frac\alpha i \right)
\le \prod_{i=1}^n\exp\left( - \frac\alpha i\right)=\exp\left(-\alpha \left[1 + \frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac 1n\right]\right).
$$
Next, use [the inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156326/215011)
$$1 + \frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac 1n > \log n.$$
Notice where you use the fact that $\alpha >0$.